# Is it possible to use 'react' to wait for a number of child actors to complete, then continue afterwards?

Tags: scala, actor

I'm getting all in a twist trying to get this to work. New to scala and to actors so may inadvertently be making bad design decisions - please tell me if so.

The setup is this:

I have a controlling actor which contains a number of worker actors. Each worker represents a calculation that for a given input will spit out *1..n* outputs. The controller has to set off each worker, collect the returned outputs, then carry on and do a bunch more stuff once this is complete. This is how I approached it using `receive` in the controller actor:

```
class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case DoJob =>
          for (1 to n) sender ! Result
          sender ! Done
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The worker actor is simple enough - it spits out results until it's done, when it sends back a `Done` message.

```
class ControllerActor(val workers: List[WorkerActor]) extends Actor {
  def act() {
     workers.foreach(w => w ! DoJob)
     receiveResults(workers.size)

     //do a bunch of other stuff
  }

  def receiveResults(count: Int) {
    if (count == 0) return

    receive {
      case Result => 
        // do something with this result (that updates own mutable state)
        receiveResults(count)
      case Done 
        receiveResults(count - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

The controller actor kicks off each of the workers, then recursively calls receive until it has received a `Done` message for each of the workers.

This works, but I need to create lots of the controller actors, so `receive` is too heavyweight - I need to replace it with `react`.

However, when I use `react`, the behind-the-scenes exception kicks in once the final `Done` message is processed, and the controller actor's `act` method is short-circuited, so none of the "`//do a bunch of other stuff`" that comes after happens.

I can make something happen after the final `Done` message by using `andThen { }` - but I actually need to do several sets of calculations in this manner so would end up with a ridiculously nested structure of `andThen { andThen { andThen } }`s.

I also want to hide away this complexity in a method, which would then be moved into a separate trait, such that a controller actor with a number of lists of worker actors can just be something like this:

```
class ControllerActor extends Actor with CalculatingTrait { 
//CalculatingTrait has performCalculations method

    val listOne: List[WorkerActor]
    val ListTwo: List[WorkerActor]   
    def act {
      performCalculations(listOne)
      performCalculations(listTwo)
    }
}
```

So is there any way to stop the short-circuiting of the `act` method in the performCalculations method? Is there a better design approach I could be taking?

Comment: I've had much better luck with [Akka's actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/actors.html) than Scala's built-in actors. Have you tried implementing with that? At the very least it gets you away from the receive/react nonsense.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to have a look at Akka, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Have just been reading about Akka actors and spotted that they "guarantee message order on a per sender basis". So I updated my example such that, if the controller needed to later ask the receiver for the computed value and needed to be sure it was all complete, it could do so with a message order guarantee on only a per sender basis (the example is still scala actors, not akka).

It finally hit me, with a bit of help from @Destin's answer, that I could make it a lot simpler by separating out the part of the controller responsible for kicking off the workers from the part responsible for accepting and using the results. Single responsibility principle I suppose... Here's what I did (separating out the original controlling actor into a controlling class and a 'receiver' actor):

```
case class DoJob(receiever: Actor)
case object Result
case object JobComplete
case object Acknowledged
case object Done

class Worker extends Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        case DoJob(receiver) => 
          receiver ! Result
          receiver ! Result
          receiver !? JobComplete match {
            case Acknowledged =>
              sender ! Done
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Receiver extends Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        case Result => println("Got result!")
        case JobComplete => sender ! Acknowledged
      }
    }
  }
}

class Controller {
  val receiver = new Receiver
  val workers = List(new Worker, new Worker, new Worker)

  receiver.start()
  workers.foreach(_.start())

  workers.map(_ !! DoJob(receiver)).map(_())

  println("All the jobs have been done")
}
```

Comment: I was writing you a big, elaborate response about some possibilities (one of which was like this, but much more complicated), but if this is all you needed, awesome!

Comment: I would be interested in seeing your other approaches if you haven't discarded them?

Comment: Yeah... I threw them out when I saw that you were pleased with what you have here. As an overview, one was basically mergesort-like; everytime your worker accumulated a lot of data (say... 10 items), it would forward that data off to another worker, which would reply with a processed list. Then that parent worker would merge the results of its child workers as they came in, and, when all of the results had been merged/processed together, it would send them back to _its_ parent, propagating up until the data was back in the controller's hands. That only makes sense in a very niche case, though.

Comment: The other was like this, but... it was complicated.  The controller formed a list of functions (let's say that there were three), and then created a `WorkerManager` (and there are going to be three `WorkerManager`s total, to correspond to the three functions).  The `WorkerManager` is given the head of the list as _its_ function, and the tail to read.  If the tail isn't `Nil`, the `WorkerManager` creates another `WorkerManager` and assigns the head of the tail to it.  All workers created by the first manager will forward their results to the to second manager, who will make more workers,

Comment: and they'll forward data to another manager, etc. So... in semi-concrete pseudo-Scala it would be like: `Controller: create Manager1((data: Int) => data + 1, List((data: Int) => data * 3, (data: Any) => _.toString))` >> `Manager1: create Manager2((data:Int) => data * 3, List((data: Any) => _.toString)); def act() = // As you receive messages, new Worker((data: Int) => data + 1, msg, Manager2)` (so the workers process the data with the function and forward results to Manager2) >> etc., until `Manager3`, where the function list is empty, so the workers it spawns forward back to `Controller`.

Comment: Essentially, `Worker` and `Manager` would be only _two_ classes, and you could simply create workers and managers that did different things by having the controller pass them different functions (or having them unpeel a list of functions as they go).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `react`/`receive` entirely by using Akka actor's. Here's what you implementation could look like:

```
import akka.actor._

class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case DoJob =>
      for (_ <- 1 to n) sender ! Result
      sender ! Done
  }
}

class ControllerActor(workers: List[ActorRef]) extends Actor {
  private[this] var countdown = workers.size

  override def preStart() {
    workers.foreach(_ ! DoJob)
  }

  def receive = {
    case Result =>
      // do something with this result
    case Done =>
      countdown -= 1
      if (countdown == 0) {
        // do a bunch of other stuff

        // It looks like your controllers die when the workers
        // are done, so I'll do the same.
        self ! PoisonPill
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Akka actors are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might approach it (in way that seems to be more comments and boilerplate than actual content):

```
class WorkerController(val workerCriteria: List[WorkerCriteria]) {

  // The actors that only _I_ interact with are probably no one else's business
  // Your call, though
  val workers = generateWorkers(workerCriteria)

  // No need for an `act` method--no need for this to even be an actor

  /* Will send `DoJob` to each actor, expecting a reply from each.
   * Could also use the `!!` operator (instead of `!?`) if you wanted
   * them to return futures (so WorkerController could continue doing other
   * things while the results compute).  The futures could then be evaluated
   * with `results map (_())`, which will _then_ halt execution to wait for each
   * future that isn't already computed (if any).
   */
  val results = workers map (_ !? DoJob)
  //do a bunch of other stuff with your results

  def generateWorkers(criteria: List[WorkerCriteria]) = // Create some workers!

}

class Worker extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case DoJob =>
          // Will generate a result and send it back to the caller
          reply(generateResult)
      }
    }
  }
  def generateResult = // Result?
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the crux of the problem is that the workers emit *multiple* results for each job, so this wouldn't work. Also, wouldn't `workers map (_ !? DoJob)` defeat the point of using actors? The `map` implementation isn't multithreaded is it?

Comment: @Russell Well... like I said, you could use `!!` to get futures, which wouldn't block the thread; the message would just get sent to the actor and forgotten about by the sender until it's ready to evaluate the future.  Looking back at it, `!!` is actually the only reasonable option for what you use there.  My bad.

Comment: @Russell On the topic of workers emitting multiple results, that strikes me as a very bizarre design.  What are the circumstances that are causing your workers to need to emit multiple results?  If the workers are just created doing a sequence of unrelated computations, why not return a list or wrapper class around those results?  If they're doing compounded calculations, maybe each actor should spawn another actor, such that each actor does only one set of calculations on the given data? (Controller sends A; Actor1 does A => B; Actor2 does B => C, etc.)

Comment: Well, an example of workers emitting multiple results in this way would be the map part of the map/reduce implementation in MongoDB. (That's not written in Scala though.) I'm open to other design ideas. The wrapper class I think would lose you a good chunk of concurrency as the controller won't be able to do anything with any of the results for a particular worker until all of them are ready. I'm not quite sure what you mean with your second example, care to expand on it a little?

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, it gave me just the nudge in the right direction I needed!